# How to efficiently grab results from Linq with or without user input params

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a linq query that I would like to return results with user input data. However, if this function gets called and there is zero data from user, OR user just wants to search via data, OR just one of the other parameters, how can I efficiently write the linq to accommodate for this? Here is the Linq and function:

```
public static List<Objects.Logs.GenericLog> GetLogs(int entityId, int logLevelId, 
    DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var logsList = new List<Objects.Logs.GenericLog>();

    using(var db = CORAContext.GetCORAContext())
    {
        logsList = (from i in db.GenericLog select  new Objects.Logs.GenericLog()
        {
            EntityId = i.FkEntityId,
            LogSourceCode = i.FkLogSourceCode,
            LogLevelId = i.FkLogLevelId,
            LogDateTime = i.LogDateTime,
            LogId = i.PkLogId,
            Message = i.Message
        })
        .Where(i => i.LogDateTime >= startDate && i.LogDateTime <= endDate)
        .Where(i => i.EntityId == entityId || i.EntityId == null)
        .Where(i => i.LogLevelId == logLevelId || i.EntityId == null)
        .ToList();
    }

    return logsList;
}
```

For example, in the second and third Where(), I have || i.EntityId == null... thinking this would accomodate for is user input for Entity is null?

Will this work?

Also, how can I do this for date ranges? Can I also do the same?

Finally, is there a BETTER way to do this?

Comment: Where are you getting data from the user that they might not provide?

Comment: maybe initialize with a null-coalescing operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 2):

Split creating a query and generating a final result by `.ToList()`
When you generate a query, you can add where statements on demand, like this:

```
    public static List<Objects.Logs.GenericLog> GetLogs(int entityId, int logLevelId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            var logsList = new List<Objects.Logs.GenericLog>();

            using(var db = CORAContext.GetCORAContext())
            {

                var query = (from i in db.GenericLog select  new Objects.Logs.GenericLog()
                {
                    EntityId = i.FkEntityId,
                    LogSourceCode = i.FkLogSourceCode,
                    LogLevelId = i.FkLogLevelId,
                    LogDateTime = i.LogDateTime,
                    LogId = i.PkLogId,
                    Message = i.Message
                });
                if(someCondition) {
                     query = query.Where(i => i.LogDateTime >= startDate && i.LogDateTime <= endDate)
                }
                query = query.Where(i => i.EntityId == entityId || i.EntityId == null)
                query = query.Where(i => i.LogLevelId == logLevelId || i.EntityId == null)
                logsList = query.ToList();

            }

            return logsList;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have a method that gets a filtered set of data based on the values of the parameters passed in. But you want to make the parameters optional, so if the user wants data for all entities, they wouldn't pass in an `entityId`.

If that's the case, then you can make the arguments optional by providing a default value for them in the method signature. We can then check if the argument has the default value, and if it does, don't apply that filter; otherwise apply it.

We can do this by doing `.Where(x => argHasDefaultValue || someFilter)`. This works because if the argument has the default value, then the second part of the `||` is ignored.

For example:

```
public static List<Objects.Logs.GenericLog> GetLogs(int entityId = int.MinValue, 
    int logLevelId = int.MinValue, DateTime startDate = default(DateTime), 
    DateTime endDate = default(DateTime))
{
    using(var db = CORAContext.GetCORAContext())
    {
        return db.GenericLog
            .Where(i => startDate == default(DateTime) || i.LogDateTime >= startDate)
            .Where(i => endDate == default(DateTime) || i.LogDateTime <= endDate)
            .Where(i => entityId == int.MinValue || i.EntityId == entityId)
            .Where(i => logLevelId == int.MinValue || i.LogLevelId == logLevelId)
            .Select(i => new Objects.Logs.GenericLog
            {
                EntityId = i.FkEntityId,
                LogSourceCode = i.FkLogSourceCode,
                LogLevelId = i.FkLogLevelId,
                LogDateTime = i.LogDateTime,
                LogId = i.PkLogId,
                Message = i.Message
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: So if user passes values for the parameters, the ones set in the arguments get over written by the users?

Comment: Yep, that's how optional arguments work. You can just call `GetLogs()` with no arguments, or just specify the ones you want (using named arguments): `GetLogs(logLevelId: 3, endDate: new DateTime(2019, 12, 31));`

Comment: I also modified the answer a bit, since you can't use `DateTime.MinValue` as a default argument since it's not a compile-time constant.